# How to pass variable between two web pages with PHP without using session

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to know How to pass variable between two web pages with PHP without using session , have a DIV link  in which inside there is id i want to pass to another page when a link is clicked but i fail to do it. please help me:

firstpage.php ( where there is a link) :

```
   ......
 <?php

  $identity = $_POST['book_id'];
while($ResultsRow=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 

    ?>  
<div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
   <div class='thumbnail'>
    <a href="shopping.php?<?php echo $identity?>" target="blank">
    <input    type="text" name="book_id"  value="<?php echo 
$ResultsRow['id'] ?>"> 
</div>
  </div>
</a> <!-- end of link  -->
..........
```

Secondpage.php (where i want to retrieve book id):

```
  ....
   <p> <?php  $myvarC = $_POST['identity'];
             echo $myvarC;
         ?> </p>
   ....
```

Comment: did you try ajax?

Comment: I can't understand why you have input field inside of anchor tag.

Anyway on first page you can use <a href="shopping.php?identity=<?php echo $identity?>" target="blank">Link Text</a>

and on second page you can get the identity value in as $identity = $_GET["identity"];

Comment: @guradio Judging by the code, I think suggesting using AJAX may be out of scope of the OP's ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try something like below:

firstpage.php

```
<a href="shopping.php?identity=<?php echo $identity?>" target="blank">
```

secondpage.php

```
<p> <?php  $myvarC = $_GET['identity'];
    echo $myvarC;
?> </p>
```

Comment: @iainn I'm getting nothing on second page till now

Comment: just do print_r($_REQUEST);die; in secondpage and check weather you getting your value or not

Comment: I think the problem is that  getting value of book id is the only problem ,here `$identity = $_POST['book_id']; `     textfield `<input    type="text" name="book_id"  value="<?php echo 
$ResultsRow['id'] ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in the urlquery like
   `shopping.php?id=1234`
and then read it on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by **$_GET**;

First Page

```
<a href="shopping.php?id=<?php echo $identity?>" target="blank">
```

Second Page

```
<?php  $myvarC = $_GET['id'];
             echo $myvarC;
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Page

```
<a href="shopping.php?identity=<?php echo $identity?>" target="blank">
```

Second Page

```
<p> <?php  $myvarC = $_REQUEST['identity'];
         echo $myvarC;
     ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a correct url with parameters

```
<a href="shopping.php?id=<?php echo $identity?>" target="_blank">
```

And get that value using

```
<?php 
$myVarC = $_GET['id'];
echo $myVarC 
?>
```